# Azure ML Studio: How to get data directory path from class DatasetConsumptionConfig?

Tags: azure, azure-ml-pipelines

I am trying to read my data files from an Azure ML dataset. My code is as follows:

```
from azureml.core import Dataset
dataset = Dataset.get_by_name(aml_workspace, "mydatasetname")
dataset_mount = dataset.as_named_input("mydatasetname").as_mount(path_on_compute="dataset")
```

The type of *dataset_mount* is *class DatasetConsumptionConfig*. How do I get the actual directory path from that class? I can do it in a very complicated manner by passing the dataset_mount into a script as follows:

```
PythonScriptStep(script_name="myscript.py", arguments=["--dataset_mount", dataset_mount], ...)
```

Then, when that script step is run, "myscript.py" mysteriously gets the real directory path of the data in the argument "--dataset_mount", instead of it being *DatasetConsumptionConfig*. So, ***DatasetConsumptionConfig somehow gets converted into directory path under the hoods***. However, that's an overcomplicated and strange approach to get the thing done. Is there any direct way to get the data path from *DatasetConsumptionConfig*? Or maybe I have misunderstood something here?